# Pandas 'isin' or 'merge' function with multiple columns and dataframes conditions

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have 2 dataframes:

```
d1={'A':[1,3,5,7,8,4,6],'B':[6,4,3,8,1,7,4], 'C':[2,5,8,9,8,4,7]}

df1=pd.DataFrame(data=d1)

d2={'a':[2,8,6,5,7],'b':[6,4,9,3,2]}

df2=pd.DataFrame(data=d2)
```

Now, I would like to see which "a" and "b" values of df2 are the same as "A" and "B" values of df1. This is true for the third row of df1 and fourth row of df2 [5,3], thus the **result** will be a new column in df2 saying True.
The dataframes have different length and also different number of columns. I know there is function "isin", I can apply it when I search for pattern in one column but not in two columns at once. I also found function "merge" with indicator=True but only understand how to apply it when the dataframes have the same number of columns.
I would be very grateful for a help in this situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can indeed use `indicator=True` and a left merge, this gives you a new column with either `both` or `left_only`. You just need to convert to a boolean:

```
out = (df2
    .merge(df1[['A', 'B']].set_axis(['a', 'b'], axis=1),
           how='left', indicator=True)
    .assign(result=lambda d: d.pop('_merge').eq('both'))
)
```

Output:

```
   a  b  result
0  2  6   False
1  8  4   False
2  6  9   False
3  5  3    True
4  7  2   False
```

Intermediate without popping the `_merge` column:

```
   a  b     _merge  result
0  2  6  left_only   False
1  8  4  left_only   False
2  6  9  left_only   False
3  5  3       both    True
4  7  2  left_only   False
```

Variant if you want to assign the output as a new column of `df2`:

```
df2['result'] = (df2
    .reset_index()
    .merge(df1[['A', 'B']].set_axis(['a', 'b'], axis=1)
                          .drop_duplicates(),
           how='left', indicator=True)
    .set_index('index')['_merge'].eq('both')
)
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate a bit on the `assign` part of the code as to what it does

Comment: @KarthikS `assign` is a way to add a new column. `df.assign(A=...)` is more or less equivalent to `df['A'] = ...`. The difference is that it returns a copy of the DataFrame.

Comment: Sorry, wasn't clear on my query. I know what `assign` does, I was referring to `lambda d: d.pop('_merge').eq('both')` part

Comment: First you are using `pop`, which I pressume deletes the column `_merge` and then you are checking if the value in the now deleted column `_merge == "both"` , query is, how are you able to check the value of the column, AFTER the column has been deleted in the previous step

Comment: @KarthikS you're right, `pop` deletes the column, **and return it as a Series**, it allows to drop the column and use it at the same time. one maybe less confusing way could have been to use `indicator='result'` to name it "result" and then `.assign(result=lambda d: d['result'].eq('both'))` ;)

Answer (score 2):

```
# Create a set of tuples for quick checking
df1_set = set(zip(df1['A'], df1['B']))

# Function to check if the tuple exists in df1_set
def check_existence(row):
    return (row['a'], row['b']) in df1_set

# Apply the function to create a new column in df2
df2['result'] = df2.apply(check_existence, axis=1)
```

Output:

```
   a  b      result
0  2  6      False
1  8  4      False
2  6  9      False
3  5  3       True
4  7  2      False
```

Comment: The logic is incorrect, this would make a 5,4 row as True since there are 5 in df1.A and 4 in df1.B, but not on the same row

Comment: @mozway you are right. I edited the answer.

Answer (score 2):

**Code**

another approach, reindex might be possible

```
out = (df1
       .set_index(['A', 'B'])
       .reindex(pd.MultiIndex.from_frame(df2))
       .notna().reset_index().rename({'C': 'result'}, axis=1)
)
```

out

```
    a   b   result
0   2   6   False
1   8   4   False
2   6   9   False
3   5   3   True
4   7   2   False
```